# WebDAV server with PAM auth and system file permissions?

Tags: freebsd, samba, pam, webdav

Basically, what I'm looking for is Samba - except that I want it to be WebDAV in the front. The requirements are that the users can log in to the WebDAV dir with their system account, and files will have their user and group set accordingly.

I know there's sambadav, but frustratingly, it seems to not be possible to get write functionality with it under FreeBSD.